# Testing SMTP server is running via C#

Tags: c#, smtp

How can I test SMTP is up and running via C# without sending a message.

I could of course try:

```
try{
// send email to "nonsense@example.com"
}
catch
{
// log "smtp is down"
}
```

There must be a more tidy way to do this.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can try [saying `EHLO`](http://dpotter.net/Technical/2009/04/testing-an-smtp-server/) to your server and see if it responds with `250 OK`. Of course this test doesn't guarantee you that you will succeed sending the mail later, but it is a good indication.

And here's a sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new TcpClient())
        {
            var server = "smtp.gmail.com";
            var port = 465;
            client.Connect(server, port);
            // As GMail requires SSL we should use SslStream
            // If your SMTP server doesn't support SSL you can
            // work directly with the underlying stream
            using (var stream = client.GetStream())
            using (var sslStream = new SslStream(stream))
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(server);
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(sslStream))
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(sslStream))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("EHLO " + server);
                    writer.Flush();
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
                    // GMail responds with: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the [list of codes](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2000/05/21/smtp-replies.html) to expect.

Comment: Liking it - liking it a lot! Good one Darin!

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov tanx for your answer.. is there anyway to ckeck username & password ( smtp authentication ) is valid? i asked it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319276/how-can-i-check-smtp-server-without-sending-email .. please help me

Comment: This seems insufficient. To properly test SMTP settings, you should at least do an `RCPT TO` with some external email address (ex. `postmaster@example.com`), but bail out before sending `DATA`. This will actually test that you have relay permissions, in effect validating your username/password and/or client certificate.

Answer (score 10):

I use this method and classes to validate the credentials ([link to github](https://github.com/B2BFamily/SmtpValidator)):

```
public static bool ValidateCredentials(string login, string password, string server, int port, bool enableSsl) {
        SmtpConnectorBase connector;
        if (enableSsl) {
            connector = new SmtpConnectorWithSsl(server, port);
        } else {
            connector = new SmtpConnectorWithoutSsl(server, port);
        }

        if (!connector.CheckResponse(220)) {
            return false;
        }

        connector.SendData($"HELO {Dns.GetHostName()}{SmtpConnectorBase.EOF}");
        if (!connector.CheckResponse(250)) {
            return false;
        }

        connector.SendData($"AUTH LOGIN{SmtpConnectorBase.EOF}");
        if (!connector.CheckResponse(334)) {
            return false;
        }

        connector.SendData(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{login}")) + SmtpConnectorBase.EOF);
        if (!connector.CheckResponse(334)) {
            return false;
        }

        connector.SendData(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{password}")) + SmtpConnectorBase.EOF);
        if (!connector.CheckResponse(235)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

SmtpConnectorBase:

```
internal abstract class SmtpConnectorBase {
    protected string SmtpServerAddress { get; set; }
    protected int Port { get; set; }
    public const string EOF = "\r\n";

    protected SmtpConnectorBase(string smtpServerAddress, int port) {
        SmtpServerAddress = smtpServerAddress;
        Port = port;
    }

    public abstract bool CheckResponse(int expectedCode);
    public abstract void SendData(string data);
}
```

SmtpConnectorWithoutSsl:

```
internal class SmtpConnectorWithoutSsl : SmtpConnectorBase {
    private Socket _socket = null;

    public SmtpConnectorWithoutSsl(string smtpServerAddress, int port) : base(smtpServerAddress, port) {
        IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(smtpServerAddress);
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(hostEntry.AddressList[0], port);
        _socket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        //try to connect and test the rsponse for code 220 = success
        _socket.Connect(endPoint);

    }

    ~SmtpConnectorWithoutSsl() {
        try {
            if (_socket != null) {
                _socket.Close();
                _socket.Dispose();
                _socket = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            ;
        }

    }

    public override bool CheckResponse(int expectedCode) {
        while (_socket.Available == 0) {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        byte[] responseArray = new byte[1024];
        _socket.Receive(responseArray, 0, _socket.Available, SocketFlags.None);
        string responseData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseArray);
        int responseCode = Convert.ToInt32(responseData.Substring(0, 3));
        if (responseCode == expectedCode) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override void SendData(string data) {
        byte[] dataArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        _socket.Send(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    }
}
```

SmtpConnectorWithSsl:

```
internal class SmtpConnectorWithSsl : SmtpConnectorBase {
    private SslStream _sslStream = null;
    private TcpClient _client = null;

    public SmtpConnectorWithSsl(string smtpServerAddress, int port) : base(smtpServerAddress, port) {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(smtpServerAddress, port);

        _sslStream = new SslStream(
            client.GetStream(),
            false,
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
            null
            );
        // The server name must match the name on the server certificate.
        try {
            _sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(smtpServerAddress);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            _sslStream = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
            if (e.InnerException != null) {
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
            client.Close();
        }
    }

    ~SmtpConnectorWithSsl() {
        try {
            if (_sslStream != null) {
                _sslStream.Close();
                _sslStream.Dispose();
                _sslStream = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            ;
        }

        try {
            if (_client != null) {
                _client.Close();
                _client = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            ;
        }
    }

    // The following method is invoked by the RemoteCertificateValidationDelegate.
    private static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
          object sender,
          X509Certificate certificate,
          X509Chain chain,
          SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
        if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            return true;

        Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);

        // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
        return false;
    }

    public override bool CheckResponse(int expectedCode) {
        if (_sslStream == null) {
            return false;
        }
        var message = ReadMessageFromStream(_sslStream);
        int responseCode = Convert.ToInt32(message.Substring(0, 3));
        if (responseCode == expectedCode) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override void SendData(string data) {
        byte[] messsage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        // Send hello message to the server. 
        _sslStream.Write(messsage);
        _sslStream.Flush();
    }

    private string ReadMessageFromStream(SslStream stream) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
        int bytes = -1;
        do {
            bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to UTF8
            // in case a character spans two buffers.
            Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
            decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
            messageData.Append(chars);
            // Check for EOF.
            if (messageData.ToString().IndexOf(EOF) != -1) {
                break;
            }
        } while (bytes != 0);

        return messageData.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a infinite loop in SmtpConnectorWithoutSsl . In CheckResponse method the line while (_socket.Available == 0) should have a limit. I hit a scenario where _socket.Available was never going to equal anything other than 0. 

but, aside from that - this works perfect. been using it for about 6 months without issue.

Comment: @Samidjo I'm not sure where you see that variant at, but I do not see it anywhere in the code that produced the infinite loop. Writing this from my phone. And if 100 is default, it did not stop at 100 from what I remember. It was infinite loop in my use case.

Comment: @Samidjo my suggestion is try it. Set the line I stated to always = 0, and print out a count. Im willing to bet it will count past 100.

Comment: @HeribertoLugo take the new version, above is an old one. Go to the git repository, you will see the variable MAX_ATTEMPTS_COUNT.

Comment: @Samidjo not sure why you deleted your other comment, looks like im talking to myself. The code doesnt matter. This was years ago and I already fixed it where I needed it. No need to change code to new one. It works and thre minor issue was resolved. I made my comment to give others a heads up who might grab the code from here just as I did.

Answer (score 4):

You could open up the port (25) with a socket or `TcpClient` and see if it responds.

Answer (score 4):

Open a socket connection to the smtp server on port 25 and see if you get anything. If not, no smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice open source tool (does more than MX):
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/DNS_NET_Resolver.aspx

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6547/A-Simple-DNS-Resolver