# how to test connection is established in smtp in c# windows

Tags: c#

I want to test connection is established without sending mail.My code is below.I have put wrong email and password but i m not getting any exception.I don't want to test with email send.

```
try {
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(textboxprimarymail.Text, textBoxpassprimary.Text);
    smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
    connectionestablish.Text = "Connetion Established";
    connectionestablish.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen; 
}
catch  {
    connectionestablish.Text = "Connetion Error";
    connectionestablish.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate smtp credentials before sending mail in C# ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426098/how-to-validate-smtp-credentials-before-sending-mail-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate. Basically, there is no way. As stated in another answer here:

> There is no way.
>
> SmtpClient can not validate
>   the usernamepassword without
>   contacting the serve it connects to.
>
> What you could do is do it outside
>   SmtpClient, by opening a TCP
>   connection to the server... but
>   authentication CAN be complicated
>   depending how the server is
>   configured.
>
> May I ask WHY you need to know that
>   before sending? normal behavior IMHO
>   would be to wrap sending in
>   appropriate error handling to catch
>   exceptions here.

[How to validate smtp credentials before sending mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426098/how-to-validate-smtp-credentials-before-sending-mail-in-c)