# SMTP Credentionals checking (C#)

Tags: c#, smtp

I want to devlop a screen for entering server, Port,Username and Password for SMTP (Mail sending)

So i want to provide one button for "Test" Those credentionals

How can i check credentionls are correct or not

Comment: what language do you want to develop this in?

Comment: k.  in future, you should be more clear what language by properly filling in the tags and subject/body of the question so that you get the right people reading it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356659/how-to-test-connection-is-established-in-smtp-in-c-windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426098/how-to-validate-smtp-credentials-before-sending-mail-in-c

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to attempt to connect to the server and try to authenticate, if you get a bad authentication response from the server the credentials are bad.