# Check email credentials existence

Tags: c#, smtp, credentials

There are dozen of questions asking is smtp server working like [Testing SMTP server is running via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633391/testing-smtp-server-is-running-via-c) and [Can I test SmtpClient before calling client.Send()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372742/can-i-test-smtpclient-before-calling-client-send) and they do they work of checking by sending commands to smtp servers. They never use any credentials for testing purposes. So I'm wondering is there a way to check are these login and password valid on this smtp-server without sending a mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTP doesn't allow you login without sending an email.

have a look at the below:

[How to validate smtp credentials before sending mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426098/how-to-validate-smtp-credentials-before-sending-mail-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

My big concern when I was working on this issue is to find a solution where I do not have to send email to check if the credentials are valid or not. So after trying a bunch of the solutions offered online, I came up with my own acceptable one to **test email credentials** :

I use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) to help me out.

```
    public static bool ValidateCredentials(string username, string password, string server, int port, bool certificationValidation)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => certificationValidation;
                    client.Connect(server, port, false);
                    client.Authenticate(username, password);
                    client.Disconnect(true);

                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ValidateCredentials Exception: {0}", ex.Message));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ValidateCredentials Exception: {0}", ex.Message));
        }

        return false;
    }
```